# Rails layout show only html on mainpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to show some HTML in my layout only on the mainpage.

The code in layout:

```
<% if current_url = root_path %>
Sometxt
<% end %>
```

But it is appearing not only on the mainpage but also `/example`

Comment: And what `current_url` returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% if current_url = root_path %>
```

This will always return true as it is an assignment.  You need a double equals.

```
<% if current_url == root_path %>
```

current_url is not a method either, you want to use request.path.

```
<% if request.path == root_path %>
```

Comment: I get this error: undefined local variable or method `current_url' for #<#<Class:0x6d72a88>:0x6d71930>

Comment: So, where did you find that `current_url`?

Comment: Of course you do.  You need to implement a method that returns the current_url.  current_url is not a built in method.  Try using `request.path` instead.